# JDBC (My)SQL only fetch cell data if flag is set

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I got a table with a lot of content and a column with a flag. Sometimes I want to load all the content, and sometimes I dont - for simplification of this quiestion, I want to load the content depending only on the flag.

Is there a way to load the content depending on the flags state?

Think of the table like this:

```
+--+--------------+-----+
|id|content       |flag |
+--+--------------+-----+
| 0| lots of text |false|
| 1| lots of text |false|
| 2| lots of text | true|
+--+--------------+-----+
```

I want my ResultSet to be filled like this:

```
+--+--------------+-----+
|id|content       |flag |
+--+--------------+-----+
| 0| NULL         |false| <- only content null, otherwise full row
| 1| NULL         |false| <- only content null, otherwise full row
| 2| lots of text | true|
+--+--------------+-----+
```

How does the SQL query look like? Is this even possible?

Comment: Then use `Where Flag = true`

Comment: You can also use MySQL's `IF` function

Comment: @Taylor Could you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `WHERE` as others have mentioned or the [`IF` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if), e.g.:

```
SELECT t.id, IF(t.flag, t.content, NULL), t.flag from table t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
Select ID, Contenet, Flag
FROM YourTable
WHERE Flag = True;
```

**Result:**

```
+--+--------------+-----+
|id|content       |flag |
+--+--------------+-----+
| 2| lots of text | true|
+--+--------------+-----+
```

Comment: Well, I want to have all rows (since there are more columns in the real table I need to access)

Answer (score 0):

As Taylor hinted at (thank you for that), the solution looks like that

```
SELECT id, IF(flag, content, NULL) as content, flag
FROM table;
```

By adding and 'OR' this "filter" can be enabled or disabled by a boolean in a prepared statement as follows:

```
SELECT id, IF(flag OR ?, content, NULL) as content, flag
FROM table;
```